# I keep having the same error when trying to denoise an audio file using pywavelets and i'm not sure what to change

Tags: python, numpy, pre, pywavelets

```py
import numpy as np
import soundfile
from moviepy.editor import VideoFileClip
import pywt

def extract_audio(input_video_path, output_audio_path):
video_clip = VideoFileClip(input_video_path)
audio_clip = video_clip.audio
audio_data = np.array(audio_clip.to_soundarray(fps=44100), dtype=np.int16)

    if len(audio_data.shape) > 1 and audio_data.shape[1] > 1:
        audio_data = np.mean(audio_data, axis=1, dtype=np.int16)
    
    soundfile.write(output_audio_path, audio_data, audio_clip.fps)

def denoise_audio(input_audio_path, output_audio_path, threshold=0.2):
audio_data, rate = soundfile.read(input_audio_path)

    # Wavelet denoising
    threshold_value = threshold * np.max(np.abs(audio_data))
    denoised_data = pywt.threshold(audio_data, value=threshold_value, mode='soft')
    
    soundfile.write(output_audio_path, denoised_data, rate)

# Example usage

input_video_path = "Orson Welles Audio.mp4"
output_audio_path_extracted = "Extracted_Orson_Welles_Audio.wav"
output_audio_path_denoised = "Denoised_Orson_Welles_Audio.wav"

# Extract audio from video

extract_audio(input_video_path, output_audio_path_extracted)

# Denoise the extracted audio

denoise_audio(output_audio_path_extracted, output_audio_path_denoised, threshold=0.2)
```

It should extract the audio, denoise it, and put the new audio in a file but it gets stuck on the same error.

```
TypeError: arrays to stack must be passed as a "sequence" type such as list or tuple.
```

I can't see where the mistake is can anyone point it out? I tried changing the file types but it didn't help.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. To start, which line is the error on? Please include the error traceback.